# Arango wildcard query

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am working on building a simple arango query where if the user enters: "foo bar" (starting to type Foo Barber), the query returns results. The issue I am running in to is going from a normal single space separated string (i.e. imagine LET str = "foo barber" at the top), to having multiple wildcard queries like shown below.

Also, open to other queries that would work for this, i.e. LIKE, PHRASE or similar.

The goal is when we have a single string like 'foo bar', search results are returned for Foo Barber and similar.

```
    FOR doc IN movies SEARCH PHRASE(doc.name,
[
   {WILDCARD: ["%foo%"]},
   {WILDCARD: ["%bar%"]}
], "text_en") RETURN doc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find `Black Knight` but not `Knight Black` if the search phrase is `black kni`, then you should probably avoid tokenizing Analyzers such as `text_en`.

Instead, create a `norm` Analyzer that removes diacritics and allows for case-insensitive searching. In arangosh:

```
var analyzers = require("@arangodb/analyzers");
analyzers.save("norm_en", "norm", {"locale": "en_US.utf-8", "accent": false, "case": "lower"}, []);
```

Add the Analyzer in the View definition for the desired field (should be `title` and not `name`, shouldn't it?). You should then be able to run queries like:

- `FOR doc IN movies SEARCH ANALYZER(STARTS_WITH(doc.title, TOKENS("Black Kni", "norm_en")[0]), "norm_en") RETURN doc`
- `FOR doc IN movies SEARCH ANALYZER(LIKE(doc.title, TOKENS("Black Kni%", "norm_en")[0]), "norm_en") RETURN doc`
- `FOR doc IN movies SEARCH ANALYZER(LIKE(doc.title, CONCAT(TOKENS(SUBSTITUTE("Black Kni", ["%", "_"], ["\\%", "\\_"]), "norm_en")[0], "%")), "norm_en") RETURN doc`

The search phrase `Black Kni` is normalized to `black kni` and then used for a prefix search, either using `STARTS_WITH()` or `LIKE()` with a trailing wildcard `%`. The third example escapes user-entered wildcard characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Question about the middle query, what is the point of using Tokens in the middle query if that'll simply break down the query in to an array and then we're getting the first element, so only 'black' is taken in to consideration, am I understanding this right? what if I wanted for both 'black' and 'kni' to be taken in to consideration by the like statement?

Comment: `norm` analyzers do not tokenize. In other words, it does not split the input string into words. It turns `Black Kni` into `black kni`, keeping it a single string and preserving whitespace. `TOKENS()` thus returns an array with a single string, and I use that for `STARTS_WITH()` or `LIKE()`. It is necessary to apply the Analyzer to the search phrase because the View processes the `title` attribute values with this Analyzer too. Otherwise it will not match in many cases.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is it possible to create the above analyzer you're suggesting using the arangodb web interface? how can I create the analyzer?

Comment: It's not supported by the Web UI, but you can use the [HTTP API](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/analyzers.html) or the [JS API](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/appendix-java-script-modules-analyzers.html), typically via [arangosh](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangosh.html) as shown in my answer.